# Measure time a task spends between 2 points in linux (task profiling)

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduler, thread-priority, preemption

I'll soon start banging my head on the wall:

It's very simple really, I want to measure the time a task spends between 2 points (in Linux - 1 core - 1 CPU).
During this time the task must have total control over the CPU and NOT get interrupted by any other task or HW interrupts.

To achieve this, I'v created a kernel module to make sure the above criterions are met.
In this kernel module I've tried to:

First, disable IRQs:

- I've used spin_lock_irqsave()/spin_lock_irqrestore() - Which i presume is the right way to be sure that all local interrupts are disabled and my task has the cpu for it self during the critical region.

Then,

- Used preempt_disable() -> Since current = my task, then logically the kernel should continue running my task until I re-enable preemption -> Does not work (my_task->nvcsw and my_task->nivcsw show that a csw has occurred -> my-task got preempted)

I've tried to increase the priority of my task by changing my_task->prio and my_task->static_prio to 1 -> highest real-time prio (my_task->policy = SCHED_FIFO)...

Did not work either (my_task->nvcsw and my_task->nivcsw show that a csw has occurred -> my-task got preempted) and my_task->prio got a new prio (120) by the scheduler I presume....

Is there any way to deterministically garantee that a task does not get interrupted/preeempted in Linux? Is there any way to force the scheduler to run a task (for a short time 50-500us) until it's done?

Here is my code to enable/disable parts of the OS (the task in question sends a enable/disable commands before and after the critical region using  procfs and handled by this switch):

```
// Handle request
switch( enable ){
    // Disable OS
    case COS_OS_DISABLE:
                    // Disable preemption
                    preempt_disable()
        // Save policy
        last_policy         = pTask->policy;
        // Save task priorities
        last_prio       = pTask->prio;
        last_static_prio    = pTask->static_prio;
        last_normal_prio    = pTask->normal_prio;
        last_rt_priority    = pTask->rt_priority;
        // Set priorities to highest real time prio 
        pTask->prio         = 1;
        pTask->static_prio  = 1;
        pTask->normal_prio  = 1;
        pTask->rt_priority  = 1;
        // Set scheduler policy to FIFO
        pTask->policy       = SCHED_FIFO;
        // Lock kernel: It will disable interrupts _locally_, but the spinlock itself will guarantee the global lock, so it will guarantee that there is only one thread-of-control within the region(s) protected by that lock.
        spin_lock_irqsave( &mr_lock , flags );
        break;
    // Default: Enable OS always
    case COS_OS_ENABLE:
    default:
        // Reset task priorities
        pTask->prio         = last_prio;
        pTask->static_prio  = last_static_prio;
        pTask->normal_prio  = last_normal_prio;
        pTask->rt_priority  = last_rt_priority;
        // Reset scheduler policy
        pTask->policy       = last_policy;
        // Unlock kernel
        spin_unlock_irqrestore( &mr_lock , flags );
                    // Enable preemption
                    preempt_enable();
        break;
}
```

Comment: So by "task", you mean "user-space task"?

Comment: Yes, user-space task. It communcates with the kernel through procfs. It sends a enable/disable OS commands (handled by the code above). The user-space task also measures the time between these 2 commands (wich is strange since all interrupts should be disabled)... but still I could measure time in between (tickless-kernel behaviour may be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling interrupts is allowed only for kernel code, and only for a short time.
With the stock kernel, it is not possible to give a user-space task total control of the CPU.

If you want to measure only the time used by your user-space task, you could run your task normally and use the [`u` modifer of `perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Modifiers) to ignore interrupts; however, this would not prevent any cache effects of the interrupt handlers.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. That what I suspected as well (a user-space task can never have total control over the CPU)... bummer... I can't user perf since I need to profile a short section of a user-space program (not the whole program)... Is there any way of executing an application in kernel space?